# Why downloaded Block Size doesn't match with actual block size mentioned on network?

Tags: block, python, blocksize

I am trying to download a block(Height:474044) using an API from [here](https://blockchain.info/block-height/474044?format=json) in python. Block is obviously downloaded in JSON format. But when I store it in a file on my system it shows very weird size number, not matching with actual blocksize on network. I also tried to download data in hex format using [this link](https://blockchain.info/block/000000000000000000ff265a641721e79bbc559d8b0e4894332732109f1a3383?format=hex). But still, when I try to store it in a file(JSON/Text), It is not showing the size same as shown in block details officially. I have intentionally chosen a block before segwit BIP to avoid any further confusion. Help me to confirm my downloaded blocksize with actually mentioned on network. This question might seem naive to some users as I am new to bitcoin. Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: What size do you see?

Comment: Actual Block Size=998198, JSON File Size Stored on My System=5866321, Binary File Size Stored on My System=1996396. All sizes are in bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, there is no JSON block format - different APIs have different ways of interpreting and displaying a block in a JSON response, and none of them will ever match the block size.

Your mistake appears to be saving the actual hex block as text.

```
1996396 = 2 * 998198
```

You must write the data as an actual binary file. i.e., write `12` as the byte `0x12`, instead of saving the text "12" directly, which will write the bytes `0x3132` to disk, doubling the size of the file saved. Saving it as text will double the file size, as you've noticed already.

Comment: Yeah. Seems about right. Thanks!!